# How we can change product image on radio button click in magento.?

Tags: magento

I have to display **multiple product images** in Magento.

Now i want to change product image according to size, **is there any extension** for that or I have to make some ajdustment in that?

Comment: Just so you know, I've never seen a question answered more quickly because it was marked urgent. If you have a problem like this, you may wish to plan ahead and ask sooner so that it isn't urgent by the time you get around to asking online.

Comment: Urgent for him, not urgent for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create each product as a [configurable and several simple](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/) products. Each simple product can have it's own price, size and image. Use an extension to [dynamically switch images](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/temgra/extension/893/color-swatches) between those simple ones.